# Pause twice as long

Tags: code-golf, string, date

Your challenge is to print the input, wait any amount of time, print the input, wait twice the time you initially waited, print the input again, and so on. The initial delay must be less than 1 hour, and you must have an accuracy of +/- 5% in the subsequent delays. Other than that, there is no restriction on the delay time.

Example:

Input: `hi`.

Output: `hi` (1ms pause) `hi` (2ms pause) `hi` (4ms pause) `hi` (8ms pause) `hi` (16ms pause), etc.

Also allowed:

`hi` (1 minute pause) `hi` (2 minute pause) `hi` (4 minute pause) `hi` (8 minute pause) `hi` (16 minute pause), etc.

Input must be provided at the start of the program (STDIN, command-line parameter, function param, etc.) and will be a string.

The initial delay can't be 0.

Comment: Does the output need to be infinite, or can it stop after some amount of time?

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony it must output as long as it can (until heat death of universe, computer crash, stackoverflow, out of memory, etc)

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony only if it is something like stackoverflow, out of memory, etc. This `y=x=>(x&&alert(x),y())` would be *technically* allowed, but I would downvote it.

Comment: @programmer5000 Thanks, got it.

Comment: Can I print a newline?

Comment: @MDXF yes, you can

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

Code:

```
[=No.W
```

Explanation:

```
[        # Start an infinite loop
 =       # Print the top of the stack without popping
  No     # Compute 2 ** (iteration index)
    .W   # Wait that many milliseconds
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x9t65evF/7/v0dqTk6@jkJ4flFOiiIA)

Comment: If you start by waiting 1 second you can use `w` instead of `.W`.

Comment: @Riley I don't think that would work. `w` waits one second no matter what, and `.W` pops a and waits that many milliseconds.

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony You're right. it would have to be `Gw`.

Comment: I don't know if it's necessarily reflective of any issue in the code, but the moment I run the linked example, the engine gives me: "Warning: The request exceeded the 60 second time limit and was terminated."

Comment: @doppelgreener Yeah, the online interpreter might not be the best option in this case. Offline works like a charm though.

Answer (score 14):

## Scratch, 8 blocks + 3 bytes

[image: set [n] to [1]; forever { say [x]; wait (n) secs; set [n] to ((n) * (2)) }]

Equivalent in Python:

```
import time
n = 1
while 1:
    print("x")
    time.sleep(n)
    n = n * 2
```

Comment: why "+ 3 bytes"?

Comment: 9 blocks (e.g. Forever, n) + 3 bytes (e.g. x, 2)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
`GD@WY.T
```

The first pause is 2 seconds.

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%60GD%40WY.T&inputs=%27Hello%21%27&version=19.10.0). Or see a [modified version](https://matl.io/?code=%60Z%60DGD%40WY.T&inputs=%27Hello%21%27&version=19.10.0) that displays the time elapsed since the program started. (If the interpreter doesn't work, please refresh the page and try again).

Or see a gif:

[image]

#### Explanation

```
`     % Do...while
  G   %   Push input
  D   %   Display
  @   %   Push iteration index (1-based)
  W   %   2 raised to that
  Y.  %   Pause for that time
  T   %   Push true. This will be used as loop confition
      % End (implicit). The top of the stack is true, which produces an infinite loop
```

Comment: @programmer5000 Out of curiosity: did the online interpreter work for you?

Comment: Yes, it did, why?

Comment: @programmer5000 Thanks. Just to check. Sometimes there are timeout issues

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```
import time
def f(x,i=1):print(x);time.sleep(i);f(x,i*2)
```

Changelog:

- changed recursive lambda to recursive function (-4 bytes)

Comment: You could save a byte on the `print` statement by switching to Python 2 :)

Comment: @numbermaniac Yes, but then I'd have to switch to Python 2. :P

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
x=input('');p=1;while p*=2,pause(p),x,end
```

Saved one byte thanks to rahnema1, `p*=2` is shorter than `p=p*2`.

I can't believe I haven't been able to golf this down, but it was actually not that easy.

- The input must be in the start, so the first part is impossible to avoid.
- I need a number that gets doubled, and it must be initialized in front of the loop

  - It would be possible to use the input as a conditional for the loop, but then I would have to have `p*=2` somewhere else.
  - Pause doesn't have a return value, otherwise it could have been `while pause(p*=2)`

Comment: A trick I learned from rahnema1: `input(0)` works

Comment: @LuisMendo Unfortunately the trick doesn't work in recent version of octave :(

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica <s>34</s> <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 29 Bytes

Original solution 34 Bytes:

```
For[x=.1,1<2,Pause[x*=2];Print@#]&
```

Shave off 2 bytes with Do

```
x=1;Do[Pause[x*=2];Print@#,∞]&
```

Shave off one more Byte with @MartinEnder's recursive solution

```
±n_:=#0[Print@n;Pause@#;2#]&@1
```

@ngenisis uses ReplaceRepeated recursion to shave off another byte

```
1//.n_:>(Print@#;Pause@n;2n)&
```

Comment: `True` is `1>0`. But something like this is a bit shorter: `±n_:=#0[Print@n;Pause@#;2#]&@1`

Comment: I put the `1<2` prior to your comment.  However, your recursive solution does save a byte. Thanks @MartinEnder

Comment: `±` is one byte in CP-1252 encoding (default Windows encoding).

Comment: Even shorter: `1//.n_:>(Print@#;Pause@n;2n)&`

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>34</s> <s>28</s> <s>23</s> 22 (+2 for `-n`) = 24 bytes

3 bytes saved thanks to Value Ink!

1 byte saved thanks to daniero

```rb
loop{print;sleep$.*=2}
```

Starts at `2`, then `4`, etc.

#### Explanation

```rb
-n                       # read a line from STDIN
  loop{                } # while(true):
       print;            # print that line
             sleep$.*=2  # multiply $. by 2, then sleep that many seconds. 
                         # $. is a Ruby special variable that starts at 1.
```

Comment: It will sleep one second before reading the input, but you can enter it already

Comment: Starting the Ruby program with the `-n` flag lets you skip the initial `gets` call, because the flag will handle it for you

Comment: `print` without an argument is equivalent to `puts$_` -- one byte saved

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 113 bytes

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{for(int i=1;;Thread.sleep(i*=2))System.out.print(a[0]);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#DcyxDoMgEADQX2GEDqTtShybdOlkN@NwwbNeghyBs9oYv536Ae9VioJ5BI/qtRcBIa@@TIOagaJuJVP8dD0YmTKvRT02j0mI4z5y1qdV1Nyce08ZYbAlICZNl@ZuTPsrgrPlRWw6E9HQXXvjjqPW@sQQ@A8)

-60 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun!

Comment: +1 for "Do not use Java for golfing. It is a bad idea." Could you add a TIO link?

Comment: @programmer5000 Sure, but it doesn't work, because TIO waits for the code to finish.

Comment: You can probably use a function instead (by my reading of the question) which will greatly reduce the boilerplate needed: `void f()throws Exception{...}`

Comment: Why an interface instead of a class?

Comment: @rightfold An interface allows you to omit the `public` in `public static void main`.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino [Using arguments as input saves you 53 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#DcuxDsIgEADQX2EEB9K6krqZuDjVrelwoadcQqGB02oI3459@2sUGNMTLIp7yQxMVnwiLWIFCnLkROE1zaDYpbhncf1a3JhiKMcTNPRmd@RR9pdOlfGXGVcd36y347GEqZuVebiEsOjsETdJp@GsTK21tXZD7@Mf).

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh, I forgot I could do that. Thanks! :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino [7 bytes off](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#DcyxDoMgEADQX2GEDqTtShybdOlkN@NwwbNeghyBs9oYv536Ae9VioJ5BI/qtRcBIa@@TIOagaJuJVP8dD0YmTKvRT02j0mI4z5y1qdV1Nyce08ZYbAlICZNl@ZuTPsrgrPlRWw6E9HQXXvjjqPW@sQQ@A8)

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
function(x,i=1)repeat{cat(x);Sys.sleep(i);i=i*2}
```

returns an anonymous function which has one mandatory argument, the string to print. Prints no newlines, just spits `x` out on the screen. `i` is an optional argument that defaults to `1`, waits for `i` seconds and doubles `i`.

*-2 bytes thanks to pajonk*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#S7P9n1aal1ySmZ@nUaGTaWuoWZRakJpYUp2cWKJRoWkdXFmsV5yTmlqgkalpnWmbqWVU@z9NQz1RXfM/AA)

Comment: Why not start at `i=1` then use `i=i*2` at the end and sleep just `i`?

Comment: that's a great idea...I'll change that.

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>44</s> 43 bytes

[Crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7427/59530)

[This answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119650/59530) already provides a decent solution, but we can save some more bytes.

```
function(x)repeat{cat(x);Sys.sleep(T<-T*2)}
```

Anonymous function taking practically anything printable as argument `x`.  Starts at 2 seconds and doubles every time afterwards. Abuses the fact that `T` is by default defined as `TRUE` which evaluates to `1`.

<s>Also, as long as [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119636/pause-twice-as-long/119713#comment293167_119636) still gets a green light from OP, we can make it even shorter, but I don't think it is in the spirit of the challenge.</s> Wait times of 0 are not allowed anymore.

```
function(x)repeat cat(x)
```

Comment: look at you, abusing poor `T` like that.

in the shorter version of the answer, you don't even need braces, just a space.

Comment: Hey, if `T` doesn't like it, `T` can stand up for itself. Also, nice find :)

Answer (score 3):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 16 bytes

```
1/?!\v
T\io/>2*.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@2@ob68YU8YVEpOZr29npKX3/39iUjIA) (Not much to see there of course, but you can check how often it was printed within one minute.)

#### Explanation

```
1    Push 1 to the stack. The initial pause duration in milliseconds.
/    Reflect to SE. Switch to Ordinal.
i    Read all input.
!    Store it on the tape.
/    Reflect to E. Switch to Cardinal.
>    Move east (does nothing but it's the entry of the main loop).
2*   Double the pause duration.
.    Duplicate it.
     The IP wraps around to the first column.
T    Sleep for that many milliseconds.
\    Reflect to NE. Switch to Ordinal.
?    Retrieve the input from the tape.
o    Print it.
\    Reflect to E. Switch to Cardinal.
v    Move south.
>    Move east. Run another iteration of the main loop.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 30 bytes

```
/(?:u<q.;1A>?ou2$/r;w;q^_q.\*/
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=Lyg/OnU8cS47MUE+P291MiQvcjt3O3FeX3EuXCov&input=aGkK&speed=1000)

This maps onto a cube with side length 3.

```
      / ( ?              # The top face does the delay.  It takes the stack element with the
      : u <              # delay value, duplicates and decrements it to 0.  When 0 is hit the
      q . ;              # IP moves into the sequence which doubles the delay value.
1 A > ? o u 2 $ / r ; w  # Initiates the stack with one and the input.  For input hi this
; q ^ _ q . \ * / . . .  # gives us 1, -1, 10, 105, 104.  There is a little loop that prints 
. . . . . . . . . . . .  # each item in the stack dropping it to the bottom until -1 is hit.
      . . .              # Then the delay sequence is started om the top face
      . . .
      . . .
```

Comment: oh wow this looks like a neat language

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 37 bytes

```bash
for((t=1;;t*=2)){ sleep $t;echo $1;};
```

For some reason TIO won't show the output until you stop the program execution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@WX6ShUWJraG1domVrpKlZrVCck5paoKBSYp2anJGvoGJoXWv9//9/j9ScnHwA)

Comment: Yeah, it only returns output upon completion.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 31 bytes

```php
for(;;sleep(2**$i++))echo$argn;
for(;;sleep(1<<$i++))echo$argn;
```

sleeps 1, 2, 4, 8, ... seconds. Run as pipe with `php -nR '<code>'`

Will work until the 63rd print (on a 64 bit machine), after that there will be no more waiting.
Version 1 will yield warnings `sleep() expects parameter 1 to be integer, float given`,
Version 2 will yield one warning `sleep(): Number of seconds must be greater than or equal to 0`.

Insert `@` before `sleep` to mute the warnings.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 21 bytes

```
Prompt Str0
1
While 1
Disp Str0
Wait Ans
2Ans
End
```

Answer (score 1):

## JS (ES6), <s>44</s> <s>42</s> <s>40</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

<sup><sup>Crossed out 44 is still 44</sup></sup>

```
i=1,y=x=>setTimeout(y,i*=2,alert(x))
```

Don't like alert bombs?

```
i=1,y=x=>setTimeout(y,i*=2,console.log(x))
```

Technically correct, but loophole-abusing:

```
y=x=>(x&&alert(x),y())
```

-3 bytes thanks to Cyoce, -2 thanks to Business Cat, -2 thanks to Neil

Comment: I don't seem to be able to test this properly, but you could probably do `i=1,y=x=>(alert(x),setTimeout(y,i*=2))` to save a couple bytes

Comment: I went ahead and edited in a credit message for Cyoce; if you want to change it, feel free to edit/rollback.

Comment: How about `i=1,y=x=>setTimeout(y,i*=2,console.log(x))`?

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 61 bytes

```
import time;i=1;x=input()
while 1:print(x);time.sleep(i);i*=2
```

Similar to @L3viathan's golf, but uses `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 26 bytes

```
qKes{es1$-Y$<{W$o;2*es}|}h
```

Doesn't work properly on TIO.

The first pause is 20 milliseconds.

**Explanation**

```
q                           e# Push the input.
 K                          e# Push 20 (the pause time).
  es                        e# Push the time (number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch).
    {                       e# Do:
     es1$-                  e#  Subtract the stored time from the current time.
          Y$<{              e#  If it's not less than the pause time:
              W$o           e#   Print the input.
                 ;2*es      e#   Delete the stored time, multiply the pause time by 2, push
                            e#     the new time.
                      }|    e#  (end if)
                        }h  e# While the top of stack (not popped) is truthy.
                            e#  (It always is since the time is a positive integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 51 bytes

```
main(c,v)char**v;{puts(v[1]);sleep(c);main(2*c,v);}
```

## C, 35 bytes as a function

```
c=1;f(n){puts(n);sleep(c*=2);f(n);}
```

Takes input as a command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 62 bytes

```
@set/at=%2+0,t+=t+!t
@echo %1
@timeout/t>nul %t%
@%0 %1 %t%
```

This turned out to be a byte shorter than explicitly doubling `t` in a loop:

```
@set t=1
:g
@echo %1
@timeout/t>nul %t%
@set/at*=2
@goto g
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular), 12 bytes

```
1idp~dw2*~2j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/reticular#@2@YmVJQl1JupFVnlPX/f0YmAA)

### Explanation

```
1idp~dw2*~2j
1               push 1 (initial delay)
 i              take line of input
  d             duplicate it
   p            print it
    ~           swap
     d          duplicate it
      w         wait (in seconds)
       2*       double it
         ~      swap
          2j    skip next two characters
1i              (skipped)
  d             duplicate input
   p            print...
                etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <s>35</s> <s>33</s> <s>30</s> 29 Bytes

With a helpful hint from whatever and Joey

```
%{for($a=1){$_;sleep($a*=2)}}
```

### Explanation

```
%{          # Foreach
for($a=1){  # empty for loop makes this infinite and sets $a
$_;         # prints current foreach item
sleep($a*=2)# Start-Sleep alias for $a seconds, reassign $a to itself times 2           
}}          # close while and foreach
```

Executed with:

```
"hi"|%{for($a=1){$_;sleep($a*=2)}}
```

Comment: you should be able to use an empty for instead of the while: %{$a=1;for(){$_;sleep($a*=2)}}``

Comment: Thanks! I had tried using a for loop before but I put `for(;;)`. Didn't even try to remove the semi-colons.

Comment: Put the `$a=1` as the initialization into the `for` to save another byte (`for($a=1){...}`). Also, I'm not sure whether to count the `%`, as the actual routine you're running is just a script block. (My challenges tend to be rather strict about requiring a program, sidestepping such ponderings, but for _anything goes_ questions I'm still not quite sure how to count various ways of using PowerShell.)

Comment: @Joey, sweet that does work. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```
s=>{for(int i=1;;System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(i*=2))System.Console.Write(s);};
```

*Saved one byte thanks to @raznagul.*

Comment: You can save 1 byte by moving the `Write` statement to the body of the loop.

Comment: @raznagul Don't know how I missed that one, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 54 bytes

Uses a lengthy calculation instead of timing libraries.

```
def f(x,a=1):
 while 1:a*=2;exec'v=9**9**6;'*a;print x
```

Comment: I now notice that my answer is similar to yours. I had not read your answer when I posted, but if you would like to incorporate my solution into yours I'll happily remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 49 bytes

```
b=input();x=6**6
while 1:print(b);exec("x+=1;"*x)
```

Uses the slight delay of the `+=` operation and executes it `x` times. `x` doubles by adding one to itself as many times as the value of `x`.

It starts at `6^6` (46656) to stick to the maximum of 5% variation in the delay.

Comment: Clever, but this is a memory hog.

Comment: @eush77 yes, on my tablet it terminated after just 7 iterations of the loop! I expect it would last a few longer on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 39 bytes

```perl6
print(once slurp),.&sleep for 1,2,4...*
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#VY5dC4IwGEbv9yseyNSFTfqgC8WrCLoL@gNhOWGg29imEdFvNz@i6PZ5zzm8jeVod@yWkhlUy40RBYdTyIsCTtQcQpbK1LkTSpL6AU8b3grV2JTY5gpthHQIvQvFkwADMFoZpLqn/fLlEcfZdBxmf386H5Jk1MNwcpY/mLKydmEwZ5sSAY36/H/rk391U0DJG4etGqNpxHxbca7Rf41VtI62jLFF1x0FeQM) (`print` overridden to add timing information)

### Expanded:

```perl6
  print(        # print to $*OUT
    once slurp  # slurp from $*IN, but only once
  ), 
  .&sleep       # then call sleep as if it was a method on $_

for             # do that for (sets $_ to each of the following)

  1, 2, 4 ... * # deductive sequence generator
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 49 bytes

```
(do((a(read))(i 1(* 2 i)))(())(print a)(sleep i))
```

first delay should be `1` second.

Comment: You have 321 rep!

Comment: @programmer5000 you have 3683 rep!

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
#|.d~yT
```

Explanation:

```
#           Infinitely loop
  .d         Delay for 
      T      10 seconds
    ~y       and double T each time
 |           print input every iteration, too
```

Answer (score 0):

### TI-BASIC, 36 bytes

Initial wait period is 1 second.

```
1→L
Input Str1
checkTmr(0→T
While 1
While L>checkTmr(T
End
Disp Str1
2L→L
End
```

Answer (score 0):

## Racket, 51 bytes

```rkt
(λ(s)(do([n 1(* n 2)])(#f)(displayln s)(sleep n)))
```

### Example

```
➜  ~  racket -e '((λ(s)(do([n 1(* n 2)])(#f)(displayln s)(sleep n)))"Hello")'
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
^Cuser break
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 13 bytes

```
;{?A┘q=q*2_Zq
```

Explanation:

```
;{     Get cmd line param as A$, start an infinite loop
?A┘    Print A$, insert a newline in the QBIC syntax
q=q*2  Double q, which is a num var starting at 1
_Zq    _Z is QBIC's sleep command, this sleeps for q seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 51 bytes

```
<?php $i=1;while(1){echo $argv[1];sleep($i*=2);}?>
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. You have been downvoted because your code does not accept variable input, but has a string hardcoded. You can fix this by making this a function or using PHP's `$argv[]` command line argument list. Also, your formatting could be improved: list the language and the bytecont at the top of your post, with `##` in front of it.

Comment: To comply, remove `$str="hi";` and change the echo to this: `echo$argvs[0];` There is not space between the echo and $var, because it isn't required :). You can replace `sleep($i);$i*=2;` with `sleep($i*=2)` saving a few more bytes. We start with 2sec sleep, which is less that "the initital has to be less than 1hour" requirement.

Comment: That makes your answer valid, and 50bytes instead of 59 :)

Comment: Then you replace `$i=1;while(1){` with `for($i=1;;){` to reduce another 2 bytes more :)

Comment: whoops. `argv`, not `argvs`

Comment: I'm  using my tablet so it's hard somehow to debug

Comment: Still, it should be `$argv[1]`. `$argv[0]` is the script name. Use `-r` to avoid the PHP tag; `-R` with `$argn` instead of `$argv[1]` to save more bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

Takes the initial delay (in units of 2 seconds) as left argument and string (any array, actually) as right argument. If this isn't allowed, add the 2 bytes `1∘` to on the left hand side to tie a fixed left argument and thus convert this dyadic function to a monadic one.

```apl
{(⎕DL⍺×2)∇⎕←⍵}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@1@t8ahvqovPo95dh6cbaT7qaAdyH7VNeNS7tfZ/eGJmCZCNqaSjLR6kgAvMACoAch51LYbq7JsaEqxupQ42wUDPUAFkioJ6RqY6AA) in a slightly modified version which uses a custom function `∆_` instead of `⎕←`. The function `∆_` displays a timestamp before output.

`{` anonymous function

`⎕←⍵` output the right argument

`(`…`)∇` call the function itself, but this time with the following argument:

`⍺×2` twice the left argument

`⎕DL` **D**e**l**ay that many seconds, and return the elapsed pause time

Answer (score 0):

### SAS, 93 bytes

```
%macro p(s);%let n=0;%do%while(1);%put &s;%let r=%sysfunc(sleep(%eval((&n+1)*2)));%end;%mend;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Forth, 49 bytes

The function `f` takes a string as a parameter, which can be pushed to the stack with `S" [string]"` or `S\" [string]"` or `s\" [string]"`. See [this document](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Displaying-characters-and-strings.html) for the differences.

```
: g + dup ms dup 2over type recurse ;
: f 1 1 g ;
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#@2@lkK6grZBSWqCQWwymjPLLUosUSioLUhWKUpNLi4pTFay5rBTSFAyBMF3B@n@wkkJGpoKSQtr/r3n5usmJyRmpAA) *(Not much to see there of course, but you can check how often it was printed within one minute.)*

Answer (score 0):

## [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```
a:1
%:;echo $X;sleep $*;make -f$(MAKEFILE_LIST) $$(($**2))
```

Uses `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)` for recursion and shell's arithmetic expansion for calculation. The value of `$(MAKE)` is assumed to be just `make`. Could shave 19 more bytes speculating on the value of `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)`, but decided not to.

The input is through `X` variable which is expected to be set on the command line (`X=hi`).

---

This one is more Makey, but also more verbose (82 bytes):

```
P=$(info $X)$(shell sleep $1)$(eval$(call $0,$(shell expr $(1) \* 2)))
$(call P,1)
```

Here, Make is expanding and evaluating a variable recursively. Shell is still used for sleeping and calculation, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 85 bytes

```
a=1
loadLine
lbla
m=256
M=get m
lblT
printChar M
m+1
M=get m
if M T
wait a
a*2
GOTO a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#PcmxDkAwFAXQ/X7Fm5lI2DoZLBpLf@CKokmrIi/x@RWL9ZxC0yBmrlM4PeISiWTaroc1u1dJHzlcdzh1OHiLRaqbP8MmVhweBhWCVYtxdrOwlHJlpeYX)

Hey! This isn't the longest one here!

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>64</s> 63 bytes

```
main(int i,char**s){for(;;){dprintf(2,"%s",s[1]);sleep(i*=2);}}
```

Sleeps four seconds initially. Accepts the first command line argument as the string to repeat.

Or, if I can print a newline:

## C, 53 bytes

```
main(int i,char**s){for(;;){puts(s[1]);sleep(i*=2);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), <s>42</s> <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```
AXJargv[1]);Uargc*=2
```

Explanation:

```
A                     start main function
 X                    while...
  J       );          printing...
   argv[1]            the first command-line argument
            Uargc*=2  sleeping for an exponentially growing number of seconds
```

Comment: Links to `about:blank`? Ok...

Comment: @programmer5000 Oops, put that in there as a placeholder. Edited :D

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 45

```
incr i;while 1 {puts $argv;after [incr i $i]}
```

## [demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZHo1WHZxaDZBaEU)

---

## Alternative approach with same size

```
while 1 {puts $argv;after [expr 2**[incr i]]}
```

## [demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcTdEdUNWWF9CMGc)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 57 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and output that value on the intervals of `86*2^(i-1)` seconds (that is `1 minute 26 seconds` and doubling)

```vba
i=1:Do:Application.Wait Now+CDate(i/1E3):?[A1]:i=i*2:Loop
```

the time period may be reduced to every `1` second for +2 bytes by replacing `1E3` with `86400`